# Rails update multiple column in different data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've written the following function, but it seems too slow. 
It needs to be updated with every record.

How do I improve this in just one `update`?

```
User.where('email like (?)', '%@xxxxx.com').each do |u|
  pwd = BCrypt::Password.create(u.account)
  u.update_columns(encrypted_password: pwd)
end
```

### update

My goal is that I need to update some user's password equal to their account.

Some of their `account` is too short, so I encrypt first and then update their column `encrypted_password`. (I am using the gem `devise`)

Comment: I think there is no work around here, why? Because your steps are: 1. get all records from DB. 2. Use ruby language to modify data. 3. Update columns of the record with new value(using ORM)... If you could be more specific on your goal, what are you trying to achieve, it would be helpful for us. Try to describe the algorithm needed

Comment: @Lun4i Thanks, I've already updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to access an specific record, and over that record get an attribute, then you could consider using [`ActiveRecord/Transactions`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html).

I tried to recreate a benchmark, updating 5000 users without ActiveRecord::Base.transaction, with, and using pluck and select, after iterating 10 times:

```
def without_transaction
  User.all.each { |user| user.update email: "#{user.name}-without-transaction@mail.com" }
end

def with_transaction
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction { User.all.each { |user| user.update email: "#{user.name}-with-transaction@mail.com" } }
end

def with_transaction_and_select
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction { User.select(:name).each { |user| user.update email: "#{user.name}-with-transaction-and-select@mail.com" } }
end

def with_transaction_and_pluck
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction { User.pluck(:id, :name).each { |id, name| User.find(id).update email: "#{name}-with-transaction-and-pluck@mail.com" } }
end

require 'benchmark'
iterations = 10
Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report('without_transaction')         { iterations.times { without_transaction } }
  bm.report('with_transaction')            { iterations.times { with_transaction } }
  bm.report('with_transaction_and_select') { iterations.times { with_transaction_and_select } }
  bm.report('with_transaction_and_pluck')  { iterations.times { with_transaction_and_pluck } }
end

user                        system      total     real
without_transaction         38.890000   3.640000  42.530000 ( 44.956559)
with_transaction            24.120000   0.380000  24.500000 ( 24.816058)
with_transaction_and_select 68.140000   1.430000  69.570000 ( 70.524832)
with_transaction_and_pluck  35.760000   0.790000  36.550000 ( 36.886989)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use transaction

Answer (score 0):

In devise you can pass the password param directly, devise gem automatically encrypt.

```
User.where('email like (?)', '%@xxxxx.com').each do |u|
  u.update_attributes(password: u.account)
end
```

Comment: Oh, I mean some of the accounts are too short to be the password. So, the devise would throw the error.